# Load more action jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have serveral articles in my page

```
<article></articles>
```

Every article has an dynamic ID echoed by a PHP variable `data-price="<?php echo $pret[1] ?>"`.

Load more button is :

```
<div id="loadMore"><a> mai multe rezultate</a></div></div>
```

Code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hotel-list article:gt(4)').hide();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        $('#hotel-list article:hidden:lt(2)').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        $('#hotel-list article').not(':lt(4)').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I make this code working and load more articles on click, but if any articles has an empty ID to remain hidden.

Comment: `data-price="<?php echo $pret[1] ?>"` is this where you store the dynamic ID for the article?

Comment: @su8898 yes that is the dynamic id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/su8898/vor7w9ef/) is the JSFiddle. In this example article 7 and article 9 are hidden when clicking 'load more' because `data-price` is empty (I am not sure why you are storing an Id in an attribute named `data-price` though).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#hotel-list article:gt(4)').hide();
     $('#loadMore').click(function () {
         $('article').filter(function () {
             return $(this).data('price') != '' && $(this).css("display") == "none"
         }).show();
     });
     $('#showLess').click(function () {
         $('#hotel-list article').not(':lt(4)').hide();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP + $getJson

PHP :: getid_data.php

```
<?php

$pret = array();

echo json_encode($pret);

?>
```

jQuery ($getJSON)

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';    
    $.getJSON('getid_data.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('#hotel-list article' + val.id).css('display', 'none')
        });
    });
});
```

In the PHP, you can fill only the ID's that should be shown, and then in jquery, you can change the selector to `$('#hotel-list :not(article' + val.id + ')')`